# How to recursively truncate filenames in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I need to truncate filenames to 35 characters (including extension) so I run this script and it worked for the directory it self (PowerShell, Windows 10).

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf | rename-item -NewName {$_.name.substring(0,31) + $_.Extension}
```

Then I wanted to apply the same script including subdirectories:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.substring(0,31) + $_.Extension}
```

This script gave me an error like this for each file:

```
Rename-Item : Error in input to script block for parameter 'NewName'. Exception when calling "Substring" with the arguments "2": "The index and length must reference a location in the string. Parameter name: length"
On line: 1 Character: 62
+ ... *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.substring(0,31) + $_.Extension}
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\User\prsn..._file_name_long.pdf:PSObject) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentInvocationFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

I tried this one but it doesn't go on subdirectories:
[Command to truncate all filenames at 255 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811607/command-to-truncate-all-filenames-at-255-characters)

I found this one but it doesn't have an answer:
https://superuser.com/questions/1188711/how-to-recursively-truncate-filenames-and-directory-names-in-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use $_ that way.  I think you have to wrap it in a ForEach loop in order to get the references to work that way.  Once that's done, you'll have to specify the path of the file you want to rename as well:

Something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.pdf -File | 
ForEach-Object{
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ( $_.BaseName.SubString(0, 31) + $_.Extension )
    }
```

Notice I used parenthesis instead of curly braces.  If you use a script block it may not evaluate.  There are other ways to make it happen, but I think using parens is the most obvious.

Notice I used `$_.BaseName` instead of name.  Base name doesn't include the extension. though I don't know how your sub-string  works out I left it in for you decide.

You can combine this with [@Mathias's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62451579/4749264) or some modification of it.  That might give you a better or more reliable way to derive the new file name. I haven't tested it, but it might look something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.pdf -File | 
    ForEach-Object{        
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ( ($_.Name -replace '(?<=^.{35}).*$') + $_.Extension )
        }
```

Comment: The first answer throws an error when a filenames is less than 35 (still works fine).
The second answer removes file extension.

Comment: @7cc , Yes I got the same, and frankly expected issue with SubString indexing.  Unfortunately we're sometimes left to assume, in this case that there's a reliable expectation of the file name length.  If we were left to write for every possible issue with a given approach we wouldn't get very far.  If you don't mind I'll incorporate in the above examples.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-replace` regex operator to remove anything after the first 35 chars - it will simply ignore any string that doesn't have at least 35 characters and return it as-is:

```
$_.Name -replace '(?<=^.{35}).*$'
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct error message is
`Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.`

The reason is that the second argument is greater than the length of the file name. e.g. `"abc".Substring(0,4)` throws.

### Answer

```
$renameTarget = dir -File -Recurse *.pdf | ? { $_.Name.Length -gt 35 }
$renameTarget | Rename-Item -NewName {
  $_.name.substring(0, 31) + ".pdf"
}
```

or

```bsh
dir *.pdf -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {
  $_.name.substring(0, [Math]::Min($_.BaseName.length, 31)) + ".pdf"
}
```